# How to get list of Venues the current user manages using API from foursquare?

Tags: php, foursquare

I am working with foursquare API in android app and PHP and I am trying to get list of all the venues managed by user  using API in PHP.

But, it always give "Margo's Cargo" instead of my own venue. I used [**Managed Venues**](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/managed) API to get list of manage venues.

Please help me to get a list of venues the current user manages.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you can pot some code so we can see what is going on? Also - make sure that you are using an oauth_token that has access to all the venues you manage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean you tried it in the [API explorer](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore)? It set's the endpoint by default to `simulate/venues/managed`, which indeed returns "Margo's Cargo". Removing `simulate/` should work:

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/managed